# Why don't mineral water cans carry a deposit label?

Tags: recycling

I've been putting in the recycling bin all our "sparkling water," "mineral water," and unflavored Canada Dry cans.  But then I wondered if I could return them to the grocery store for deposits.  Apparently not -- New York State says if there's a deposit, that information needs to be clearly displayed on the can; the can makes no mention of a deposit.

Why is there no deposit on these cans?

Here is an example of such a can:

[image: sparkling water can]

I live in New York state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure it doesn't? In sparkling water cans, sometimes the deposit label is stamped on the top (from a sparkling water I'm about to enjoy):

[image]

The New York State Department of Environmental Conservation has a list of ["Frequently Asked Questions About the Bottle Bill"](https://www.dec.ny.gov/chemical/57687.html) which confirms that there is a deposit for these types of beverage cans (emphasis added):

> What beverages are covered by NY’s Bottle Bill?
>
> - Carbonated Soft Drinks
> - Including **Sparkling Water**
> - Carbonated Energy Drinks
> - Carbonated Juice (anything less than 100% juice, containing added sugar or water)
> - Carbonated Tea
> - **Soda Water**
> - Beer and Other Malt Beverages
> - **Mineral Water – Both carbonated and non-carbonated mineral water**
> - Wine Products
> - **Water which does not contain sugar, including flavored or nutritionally enhanced water**

Comment: Yay, you're right.  I will say that even now that I know where to look, and even in a strong light, it is VERY hard to see.